# I want to update or manage my executable file (which is a QT application) running on raspberry pi over the air (OTA), how to do it?

Tags: linux, sqlite, server, raspberry-pi, ota

I want to check the current software version from server and update the file if newer version is available
Version check will take the data from database , and send it to the server to check the version.

I tried to do it with aws IOT core, if anyone can tell or help me how it can be done that will be really appreciated